# Array incompatibility Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I construct the square array as I have and then pass it to the new Float32Array, I get an error, however, when I pass temp to Float32Array (and manually assign numTriangles to 6), everything works properly... asdf is logged to the console in both attempts, not sure why this is happening.

```
  var square = [[-1,-1,],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,1]];
  var numTriangles = square.length;
  square = square.join();
  var temp = [-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1];
  if (square == temp) {
    console.log("asdf");
  }
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(square),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numTriangles); //numTriangles == 6
```

Comment: "An" error? It does not report which one? That's strange.

Comment: you need to give new typed arrays flat Arrays, they can't store 2-col sub-arrays, just numbers...

Comment: -dandavis, I did pass a flat array, the square.join() removed the sub-arrays, hence the "asdf" being logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `join()` [produces a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin), not an array. Float32Array cannot take neither a string or a 2-dimensional array as argument.

A somewhat hackish way to get around is to parse the string after join() as JSON:

```js
var square = [[-1,-1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,1]],
    float;

float = new Float32Array(JSON.parse("[" + square.join() + "]"));
console.log(float);
```

However, this has performance impacts. The better way is to loop through your array and flatten it while updating the typed array:

```js
var square = [[-1,-1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,1]],
    len = square.length,
    float = new Float32Array(len * 2),
    i = 0, t = 0;

while(i < len) {
  float[t++] = square[i][0];
  float[t++] = square[i++][1];
}

console.log(float);
```

The latter has more code but is [many times faster](http://jsperf.com/flatten-2d-array-using-join-json-or-loop) than the first approach.

PS: you also have an extra comma in the array which should not be there.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, totally forgot join makes a string, though, why does asdf get logged when comparing an array with a string?

Comment: @user3654525 the == is not explicit type-wise so the array will be converted to string first, then compared. If you had used triple === it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays pointed by `square` and `temp` are references to corresponding arrays. So these references are always different, because the first is a result of `.join()` method, and the second is a reference to a static in-line array.

You need to compare each element of both arrays in a cycle.